# Ruby Profiling results show inconsistent results

Tags: ruby, profiling

I am profiling my Rails application for performance optimization

Most of the code flows are profiled appropriately

But some code flows give my very weird profile results and I don't know how to interpret that.

For Eg: I have a parent method with following results

```
Total time: 4.5 sec
Wait time: 0.0 sec
Self time: 0.0 sec
Child time: 4.5 sec
```

But the time taken in any of the child methods is not more than 0.0 sec

This occurs for many methods. I have tried with ruby-prof and newrelic and both the profilers give me similar results.

Also some of my child methods are listed under parent methods which actually never call them.

Everything seems very random for these calls. Has anyone faced such an issue before?

Am i missing something?

Comment: Please include some of your code. See the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I've come across that sort of problem in the past, and have traced these sorts of issues to things like child methods "appearing" due to dynamic code injection in dependent gems or child methods that are at first glance trivial in execution taking longer due to current system conditions (high memory pressure, slow disk, etc.).

My suggestion in hunting down cause would be to start commenting out code and checking your profiling results. The simple act of removing entire branches of code from consideration in your profiling, and then iteratively re-adding pieces until you've identified the point where your mysterious methods suddenly reappear can be instructive in identifying what's going on.